# JUnit test not catching exception

Tags: java, junit

UPDATE: Here's the full test:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testMissingData() throws Exception{
Resource<ObjectDataModel, Content, Status> resource = builder.build(content,  argA1Response, 
            argA2Response, objFilterParam, argA3Response);}
```

And here's the *build* method:

```
public Resource<ObjectDataModel, Content, Status> build(Content argContent,
        ResponseA1 argA1Response,
        ResponseA2 argA2Response, String argObjectTypeFilter,
        ResponseA3 argA3Response) {

    try {
        viewDataModel.setObjectType(this.buildObjectType(filteredObjectType,
                argA1Response.getData().getDataObject().getCategories().get(0).getObjectTypes().get(0)));

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "Exception occoured while buildng the Object Data Model";
        LOG.error(msg, e);
    }

    // we have the required information gathered to return
    return Resource.okFromDataAndContent(viewDataModel, argContent);
}
```

And here's the *buildObjectType()* method:

```
private ObjectType buildObjectType(ObjectTypes argA1ProductType,
        PendingObjectTypes argA2ProductType) {
    ProductType objectType = new ObjectType();
    List<Plan> plans = argA1ObjectType.getPlan();
    List<PendingObjectSummary> objPlans = argA1ObjectType.getData();

    if (objectType.getData() == null) {
        objectType.setData(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    PendingObjectSummary tempPlan = null;
    for (Plan currPlan : plans) {
        tempPlan = plans.stream()
                        .filter(plan -> plan.getObjId().equals(currPlan.getObjId()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);

    }

    return objectType;
}
```

I'm using an *Optional* to test for null and I can confirm that the exception is being thrown -- but JUnit isn't catching it. Here's the test case:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testMissingData() throws Exception{
    Object<> response = fixture.create();

    assertNotNull(response);
    assertNotNull(response.getData());

    assertNull(resource.getData().getObjectType()); 
}
```

In my *create* method I'm simply iterating over a bunch of objects to try and find one that matches my ID; if not found then throw a *NullPointerException*:

```
for (Object currObj : objects) {
        tempObj = myOtherCollection.stream()
                        .filter(obj -> obj.getId().equals(currObj.getId()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);
    }
```

The JUnit output clearly isn't catching the exception - here's the output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And my tomcat logs are definitely throwing the exception here:

```
18:48:30.015 [main] ERROR com.myCompany.src.ModelBuilder - Exception occoured while buildng the Data Model
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
```

The only issue I can see is that maybe where I assign *tempObj* that the code is wrong. Am I missing anything obvious? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: As long as we don't see your full code for the test and the class under test we can not verify if in your test case `myOtherCollection` is empty or not.

Comment: myOtherCollection isn't empty - I've confirmed thru debugging.

Comment: Seeing that your run time code throws `NullPointerException` does not confirm that your UT does so too. Catch any exception in the UT and put a breakpoint there to see what is actually being thrown.

Comment: So why do you think the code should throw the NPE at all during testing?

Comment: My UT does not throw an exception. The code in that create method does. I'm new to JUnit and am probably missing something easy. Am I wrong to expect to catch a null pointer thrown by the runtime? When I debug the test I can see the last assertNull(resource.getData().getObjectType()) assertion is passing. So, I'm seeing the null object that I expect -- but I'm hoping to catch the runtime error.

Comment: It would be best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why do you assert the resulting Object if you expect an exception? Correct me if I am wrong but I think that if an exception is thrown in fixture.create() your assertions would not be evaluated.

Comment: @Smutje - I'm brand new to JUnit so I probably don't understand how it works. AFAIK if my runtime enviro throws a NPE then I should be able to add: @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class) and catch it. Is that wrong?

Comment: Comment out your code and put in a `throw new NullPointerException();` in your test. That'll tell you if JUnit works :)

Comment: @Scratte - yes, that makes the JUnit test pass. The runtime still throws the NPE.

Comment: FYI: throwing a NPE if your Optional is empty defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'm confused. With no code in your test except for thowring a NPE, you're getting another NPE while running your test?

Comment: In the runtime, yes. When I explicitly throw the NPE the test passes; however, the Optional is still throwing an NPE - which I expect.

Comment: Running a test is a runtime thing. You can't not have a runtime when you're running a test. So what do you mean with runtime? And what's in resource?

Comment: @Scratte - I've added the full code but removed specific references.

Comment: why do you have inside `for`, `streams` on the same object `plans` ? Also in `build` method you are handling exceptions so any exceptions is not thrown, also you are `catching` `Exception` but expecting `NullPointerException` but by catching `Exception` you are handling any exceptions which will be thrown.

Comment: so the catch block of the build() method prevents the exception from being passed to my test?

Comment: yes, buy handling you are not throwing. If you want throw exceptions from `build` use `private void build() throw NullPointerException`

Comment: Where is `resource` declared? Your test cases initializes `response`, but you `assertNonNull` for `resource.getData().getObjectType()`.

Comment: @daniu in test it is initializes `resource` object

Comment: @noname No it does not. Where?

Comment: @daniu first code block, which he provide

Comment: @noname `Object<> response = fixture.create();`? Initializes `response`, not `resource`.

Comment: @daniu just check first block of code  `...resource = builder.build(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are catching the nullpointer exception so the exception is not propagated to your test.

see

```
try {
    viewDataModel.setObjectType(this.buildObjectType(filteredObjectType,
            argA1Response.getData().getDataObject().getCategories().get(0).getObjectTypes().get(0)));

}
catch (Exception e) {
    String msg = "Exception occoured while buildng the Object Data Model";
    LOG.error(msg, e);
}
```

If you want to test for an exception you could throw an exception in your error handling (for example a custom ObjectCreationExcepion) and assert that that one is thrown, like

```
try {
    viewDataModel.setObjectType(this.buildObjectType(filteredObjectType,
            argA1Response.getData().getDataObject().getCategories().get(0).getObjectTypes().get(0)));

}
catch (Exception e) {
    String msg = "Exception occoured while buildng the Object Data Model";
    LOG.error(msg, e);
    throw new ObjectCreationException(msg);
}
```

and in your test

```
@Test(expected = ObjectCreationException.class) 
public void testMissingData() throws Exception{
    Object<> response = fixture.create();  
}
```

*@Test(expected = ObjectCreationException.class)* only handles exceptions that are not handled within the tested code OR the test itself.

Comment: Ok - this I understand. The catch block of the build() is the problem. Exceptions need to bubble up to Test. So, instead of testing for an exception I can probably just as easily test for null on the returned object.

Comment: I don't think the final application is meant to throw an exception :)

Comment: @fumeng yes, @Test(expected = ObjectCreationException.class) only handles exceptions that are not handled within the tested code OR the test itself. This is also true for the junit5 variant.

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do is

```java
public Resource<ObjectDataModel, Content, Status> build(Content argContent,
        ResponseA1 argA1Response,
        ResponseA2 argA2Response, String argObjectTypeFilter,
        ResponseA3 argA3Response) throws NullPointerExceptions // << notice thrwoing declatration
{ // do some stuf}
```

and then in test you can handle it like you where trying by

```java
public void testMissingData() throws Exception{
Resource<ObjectDataModel, Content, Status> resource = builder.build(content,  argA1Response, 
            argA2Response, objFilterParam, argA3Response);
}
```